# If - else if statement - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am new to coding and I have a doubt with respect to if - else if statements for props

The following code snippet is working, but I want to add another property in props and if 'abc' is unavailable, only then props value 'pqr' should be added to path.

```js
 render() {
    if (this.props.abc?.status !== 'available') return null;
      console.info('Log value= ',this.props);

    const path = this.props.abc.value;
    
    return (
      <View
        getfile={path}   
       console.info('finished loading:', path); 
        }
      />
    );
  }
```

I want to write something like

```js
render() {
        if (this.props.abc?.status !== 'available') return null;
        else if (this.props.pqr?.status !== 'available') return null;
          
          console.info('Log value= ',this.props);
          
        if (this.props.abc != null) {
        const path = this.props.abc.value;
        }
        else if (this.props.pqr != null) {
        const path = this.props.pqr.value;
        }
/* I know the above if -else if statement will fail as props value for 'abc' might not be null yet not have the required value in which case it would never go to the else if statement. */
        
        return (
          <View
            getfile={path}   
           console.info('finished loading:', path); 
            }
          />
        );
      }
```

Here, I want to check if props value is available for abc or pqr and then it should assign that value. How do I code better?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Well if props is not available it will go into the first if and exit.  So it will never get down to the unavailable check

Comment: `else if (this.props.abc?.status !== 'available')` is the same condition as `if`. Did you mean to write `pqr` instead of `abc` there?

Comment: @epascarello the props value is coming from a widget so I can either pass value to abc or to pqr. so the condition mentions if props value status for abc is not available it should check props value for pqr

Comment: The problem with your if is that when it is not set, it will exit out. It will not continue on.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that was a mistake I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it to something like this.

- Get the `abc` and `pqr` properties from `this.props` using destructuring
- Create a variable and assign it to `abc ?? pqr`. If `abc` is null, `nested` will be equal to `pqr`.
- `!==` negative test will be true if `nested?.status` returns undefined. So, check if `nested?.status === 'available'`. It will return false if `nested` is null or `nested.status` is something other than 'available'

```js
const { abc, pqr } = this.props;

const nested = abc ?? pqr;

if (nested?.status === 'available') {
  const { path } = nested;
  return <View... >
}

return null
```

---

You can further simplify it. But, I feel it is less readable

```js
const { abc, pqr } = this.props;
const { status, path } = abc ?? pqr ?? {};

if (status === 'available')
  return <View... >

return null
```

Comment: Thanks @adiga another issue with this is that, I want to set path = abc.value.uri (in case file is available in abc) or path = pqr.value, so should I be writing an if-else for that?